# Optical Parametric Amplifier performance compared to Optical Parametric Oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-entanglement

I am trying to design a bright source of polarization entangled beams of photons so that it is visible to human eye. I have to decide between OPA and OPO. OPAs are cheap and simple to develop compared to OPOs. Which one will perform better for polarization entanglement experiment with beams and why?

Comment: The human eye can't see polarization (much) and it is insensitive to entanglement (apart from the fact that an ordinary entangled state does not even survive the amplification process, it seems), since it can't act as a correlation device (at least I don't see how). It seems to me that you might as well use a photomultiplier and control an LED with it (or, better, with the output of the correlator in your experiment).

Comment: Well what I intend to do is make one beam V polarized with a polarizer  and place another polarizer in the path of other beam to show entanglement by changing its orientation. I thought with beam entanglement this experiment is feasible. People will be able to "see" it happening.

Comment: Entanglement shows up in the correlation of two measurements. It doesn't show up in any one measurement alone. You can clearly "see" that on your computer screen once you tally your polarizations and do the math. What I am missing is how you are going to do the correlations on what I believe would now be non-entangled amplified signals. I hope a specialist can shed light on the question if a macroscopic entangled quantum state of light can be created with an amplification mechanism.

Comment: see this link  http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0511038 ...sry i do not know how to embed a link in comment box

Comment: If I understand this paper correctly, what we get with that are rapid polarization fluctuations which the human eye can't detect, either, and we still need a correlating device. I am also not sure if this technically qualifies as an entangled state since it seems to become a matter of classical correlation. Maybe I am misunderstanding the paper. I will think about it.

Comment: @user43794 It seems that this experiment will only demonstrate correlation of the polarizations, not entanglement.

Answer (score 0):

An optical parametric oscillator amplifies vacuum fluctuations using the energy of the pump beam, while an optical parametric amplifier amplifies an already existent second pump beam.

Urea with nonlinear coefficient 1.4 pm/V transparency for light with wavelength 200 nm -1.4 micrometers and barium borate with 2.2 pm/V and transparency 189 nm -3.5 micrometers are what I use for optical parametric oscillator. Urea can reach a maximum of 20% efficiency at a phase matching of 90 degrees;

The longer the crystals on the optical axis,the higher the efficiency.